# Closest generators for matrix algebra which is not semisimple

Tags: linear-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Given a collection of $n$ commuting $n \times n$ matrices $A_1, \dots, A_n \subset M_n (\mathbb{R})$ which generate a semisimple algebra $\mathcal{A}$, I am interested in finding matrices $E_1, \dots, E_n$ which minimize $||(E_1 \ \cdots \ E_n)||$ subject to the algebra generated by $A_1+E_1, \dots, A_n+E_n$ not being semisimple. Here $||\cdot||$ is any norm and the $A_i+E_i$ need not commute.

My approach was to use the fact that if $A_1, \dots, A_n$ form a basis for the algebra $\mathcal{A}$ (which is generically the case since they commute) then $\mathcal{A}$ is semisimple if and only if the matrix with $ij$ entry equal to $trace(A_i A_j)$ is invertible. I can then try to get bounds on the perturbation so as to guarantee that the matrix $(trace((A_i+E_i)(A_j+E_j)))_{ij}$ is invertible.

This approach somewhat works, but appears to give very suboptimal bounds, as the matrix in question also is not invertible if the $A_i$ are not linearly independent. I think in most cases I am more so detecting the distance to a collection of matrices which is not linearly independent.

I'd like to know if there is any literature which addresses this type of problem.